# How can i export a record from Openrefine using a template without getting empty elements?

Tags: templates, export, openrefine

[image: screenshot of "record" in OpenRefine, that i would like to export]

My Export template looks like this:

(a part of it)

`<record> {{forNonBlank(cells["subject"], v, "<dc:subject xml:lang=\"" + forNonBlank(cells["lang"], v, v.value, "") + "\">"+v.value+"</dc:subject>", "")}} {{forNonBlank(cells["description"], v, "<dc:description xml:lang=\"" + forNonBlank(cells["lang"], v, v.value, "") + "\">"+v.value+"</dc:description>", "")}} </record>`

And the result i get looks like this (a part of it):

`<record> <dc:subject xml:lang="de"></dc:subject> <dc:description xml:lang="de"></dc:description> </record>`
`<record> <dc:subject xml:lang="en"></dc:subject> <dc:description xml:lang="en">reviewed</dc:description> </record>`

How do i manage to avoid exporting the empty cells, and have all the elements contain values? (which they do)
It doesn't matter if i work in row or record mode, the export result is the same.

many thanks for your help!

Comment: It's kind of hard to just do this by inspection without any test data, but have you tried using cells["subject"].value in your forNonBlank conditional?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me!

I have tried only this: {{forNonBlank(cells["subject"], v, "<dc:subject xml:lang=\"" + forNonBlank(cells["lang"], v, v.value, "") + "\">"+v.value+"</dc:subject>", "")}}

Comment: It sounds like the answer to my question is No? If so, I recommend trying forNonBlank(cells["subject"].value in place of forNonBlank(cells["subject"]. Ditto for the other columns.

Comment: If i use {{forNonBlank(cells["ID"].value, v, "<dc:identifier type=\"providerItemID\">"+v.value+"</dc:identifier>", "")}} i get nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

Comment: I don't see an "ID" column in your screenshot. I would suggest posting your problem to the OpenRefine mailing list/Google Group, along with some example data that people can use to replicate your spreadsheet. It only needs to be a couple of lines, but without that no one is going to take the time to recreate your project from a screenshot just so they can debug your problem. Good luck!